# lambda query to filter out duplicates and nulls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lambda

Say I have MyTable with MyField1 and MyField2, MyField3 populated as follows

```
MyField1      MyField2    MyField3
A1            null        x
A1            123234      x
B1            47686876    x
C1            null        x
C1            8856578     x
D1            null        x
E1            23423       y
```

How can I write a lambda query to only bring back records where MyField3 = 'x' and there is either:
only one occurrence of MyField1, OR
Where there are 2 occurrences, only take the one where MyField2 is populated?
There will only ever be at most 2 occurrences of MyField2.

So far I have

```
MyList = db.MyTable.Where(p => p.MyField3 == "x")
```

I know it's bad table design (different field names obviously) but I just inherited it.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code

```
MyList = db.MyTable.Where(p => p.MyField3 == "x" && p.MyField2!=null).Distinct();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, how do I also bring back where I only have one occurrence of MyField1, D1 in the data example in my post?

Comment: I'm guessing a UNION on your query and one to bring back the single occurrences...

Answer (score 0):

This clause will give you the records where `MyField2 is null` and `MyField1 is unique`:

```
var MySecondList = db.MyTable.Where(p => p.MyField2 == null)
    .GroupBy(g => new 
    {
        myField1 = g.MyField1 
    })
    .Select(s => new 
    { 
        count = s.Count(), 
        myField1 = s.Key.myField1 
    }).Where(k => k.count == 1).ToList();
```